# Excel - Match Cell Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two worksheets in the same workbook

[image]
[image]

The first screenshot is Worksheet A. 
The second screenshot is Worksheet B.

Question:
How to match SIZE PERCENTAGES numbers according to the columns “Line”, “Sub-Line”, “Category”, “Sub-Category”, “Occasion” and “Size Pack”?

For example, in Worksheet A, under the “S1” heading, J11's cell value should be 18%, following the tabular data demarcated in red borders in both Worksheets A and B.

Many thanks!

Comment: Use same logic as in your other post for retrieving quantity. For Column of INDEX of range I:O of Worksheet B use `ROW()-13`.

Comment: Have a try and share us the formula you tried (that work/stuck) with.. /(^_^)

Comment: PS judging from your previous question and this one about sizing with (almost) similar data and different start of range. I want to suggest you use one data set containing all info and calculate from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me!

=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(B10,"-",C10,"-",E10,"-",F10,"-",D10,"-",L10),'Worksheet2'!$G$9:$O$44,MATCH('Worksheet1'!$O$9,'Worksheet2'!$G$9:$O$9,0),FALSE)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve a lookup value based upon multiple columns / conditions, use the following (screenshot 1 / sheet [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9610e6F5WiikN-skb?e=5gmS1S) refer):

```
=INDEX($O$3:$O$7,MATCH(A3:A7&B3:B7&C3:C7&D3:D7&E3:E7,J3:J7&K3:K7&L3:L7&M3:M7&N3:N7,0))
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

**REVISON**

If you want to return multiple values, the same basic approach can be used (screenshot 2, here [refer](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9610e6F5WiikN-skb?e=LHvOAz)):

```
=INDEX($O$3:$R$7,MATCH(A3:A7&B3:B7&C3:C7&D3:D7&E3:E7,J3:J7&K3:K7&L3:L7&M3:M7&N3:N7,0),F2)
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in `J11`:
`=INDEX('Worksheet B'!$I$11:$O$31,MATCH(1,($B11='Worksheet B'!$B$11:$B$31)*($C11='Worksheet B'!$C$11:$C$31)*($D11='Worksheet B'!$F$11:$F$31)*($E11='Worksheet B'!$D$11:$D$31)*($D11='Worksheet B'!$F$11:$F$31),0),COLUMN()-9)`
Entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Works just like my previous formula, only the indexed rows are counted from the column number -9 (that's 10-9 = 1 for column J)